# Creating permanently differing changes across branches in git

Tags: git, google-app-engine, merge, branch

This question specifically relates to the use of git and GoogleAppEngine, but it the answer could well be of use to anyone that has branches destined for different environments.

We are seeing an issue with unwanted code persistently cross contaminating branches during merge.

Some Background: We are using git to manage code that's being uploaded to GoogleAppEngine. We have 3 main branches (master, staging and development) and each has it's own separate GAE project.  The standard way of deploying to GAE is via a Gradle plugin, which uses a single xml configuration file (fixed name and fixed location in the directory hierarchy) to specify the target GAE project and version number.

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>projectname-development</application>
    <version>307</version>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
</appengine-web-app>
```

So, this file has been modified on each branch to have the correct `-live` and `-staging` postfixes to the `<application>` tag.

Our work process is complex, but not unusual.  New features are branched from development and merged back into development (--no-ff so we can see the branch history).  Development is then merged into staging.  Staging is merged into master.  Bug fixes to staging are branched to a bugfix branch, then merged back to staging and backward to development.

Our problems are occurring when we start merging between the primary branches or bugfix to development branch.  git resolves the merge by replacing the GAE target project in the XML most of the time.  I could understand this on the first merge (because this is where it became divergent), but we perform the merge with --no-ff and --no-commit so we can update the version numbers correctly (as they get incremented as part of our merge policy) and git appears to be trying to merge the incorrect content every time merge is used.

The 'psuedocode' for this problem would be as follows:-

Create initial branches...
1. Commit xml file to master.
2. Branch master to development
3. Change GAE target project in the xml in development and commit

Develop a feature...
4. Create feature branch from development, make feature, increase version number, merge back to development
5. Merge development to master with --no-ff and --no-commit

At this point, as expected it will merge the GAE target project and version from development to master.  We manually correct GAE target project back to what it was on the master branch, but leave the change to version number; and commit.

Develop another feature...
6. Create feature branch from development, make feature, increase version number, merge back to development
7. Merge development to master with --no-ff and --no-commit

At this point, things are not as expected.  Git has changed both the version number **and the GAE target project**.  Without trying it, I'm 99.9% sure that other source control (SVN, Vault or Perforce in my experience) would have only merged the version number, which is the outcome I would have expected here.

We didn't initially notice the issue because SourceTree was hiding changes from us (not shown in the log at all?!).  It was only when performing this from command line and looking at every step along the way that we noticed where the issue was coming from.  It's almost like git is being too clever and it's figuring that as we've not committed that hunk (because we manually edited the file before commit) that we have done some sort of cherry pick and it tries to do a deferred merge at a later stage.

So, my question is "How do we tell git that when we have committed our merged file from branch B to branch A, that we have taken all the changes from it we want?", or is there a better/different solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's almost like git is being too clever and it's figuring that as we've not committed that hunk (because we manually edited the file before commit) that we have done some sort of cherry pick and it tries to do a deferred merge at a later stage.

This cannot be true. Git only tracks the snapshot of what was committed. It does not care how or why you got to that point.

I tried your example, but I only has an issue when consecutive lines were conflicting, i.e., the version number changed in dev, and the application name was different between dev and master. In this situation I got a conflict, but this is expected, because Git notices that the changed line does not neatly fit into a context in the target branch that otherwise matches the original branch.

However, when the version number was separated from the application name by 4 lines I had no issue, and only the version number got affected, not the application name.

In any case, storing transient information in program files might not be a goof idea. It might be better to keep the version number and application name in a property file that never gets committed, and then have a quick script that updates reads the property file to set the XML file to have the right values. Better yet, most tools allow you to declare variables based on property files. Try to investigate if your build tool supports that.

**EDIT:**

The version number might be necessary, but the application name should not be committed on any branch. Instead, use a placeholder and either a checkout hook or `.gitattributes` filter that will replace the placeholder with the appropriate application name based on the current branch.

For more info see 
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks
and 
http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: I was confused by git's behaviour in this case too.  I still have no explanation for what I'm seeing as I would have expected a conflict, but instead it's just silently replacing content (hence our issue).  We are seeing the same problem where we are doing bugfix branches.  i.e. branch from staging, fix bug and increase version number.  It doesn't matter if we merge the bugfix to development or merge it back to staging, then merge staging to development.  Both cases try and take the GAE target project over without conflict.  My only other thought is maybe a whitespace setting?

Comment: We need to store both the version number and GAE Project Name in the repo.  The former because we have multiple developers working on it at once and the version numbers need to be kept in step.  The latter for ease of deployment in what has been up till now a highly error prone and painful build system.  I've only just inherited it and previously it was an svn repo with no branches, 3 copies of the code and all of the build output committed!  A merge consisted of copying files between folders...

Comment: OK, looks like git hooks are the way I want to go with the targets, which is a much better solution than what we have currently.  We think we finally got to the bottom of our merge wierdness though.  SourceTree was sometimes doing a ff when merging, even when asked not to.